# How to convert pandas dataframe into a transaction matrix

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, chain, markov

I want to convert my pandas dataframe into a markov chain transaction matrix

```
import pandas as pd

dict1={'state_num_x': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1,3: 1,4: 2,5: 2,6: 2,7: 3,8: 3,9: 4,10: 5,11: 5,
                 12: 5,13: 5,14: 5,15: 5,16: 6,17: 6,18: 6,19: 7,20: 7,21: 7},
 'state_num_y': {0: 1,1: 1,2: 2,3: 5,4: 1,5: 4,6: 6,7: 1,8: 6,9: 1,10: 1,11: 2,
                 12: 3,13: 5,14: 6,15: 7,16: 1,17: 2,18: 5,19: 1,20: 4,21: 6},
 'Sum_Prob': {0: 0.9999999999999999,1: 0.0369363131137667,2: 0.7408182206817178,
  3: 0.22224546620451535,4: 0.0369363131137667,5: 0.7408182206817178,
  6: 0.22224546620451535,7: 0.17028359283647593,8: 0.8297164071635239,
  9: 0.9999999999999999,10: 0.003599493183089517,11: 0.08889818648180613,
  12: 0.13334727972270924,13: 0.021335564755633474,14: 0.012001255175043838,
  15: 0.7408182206817178,16: 0.015600748358133354,17: 0.8297164071635239,
  18: 0.1546828444783427,19: 0.015600748358133354,20: 0.8297164071635239,21: 0.1546828444783427}}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
```

It looks like

```
state_num_x state_num_y Sum_Prob
0           1           1.000000
1           1           0.036936
1           2           0.740818
.           .           .
.           .           .
7           1           0.015601
7           4           0.829716
7           6           0.154683
```

let's called the result array arr_tx

arr_tx[0][1] should be equal to 1

arr_tx[1][1] should be equal to 0.036936

arr_tx[1][2] should be equal to 0.740818

it should be an 8x8 matrix and missing values should equal to zero.

So final result should look like

```
 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0.036936,0.740818,0,0,0.222245,0,0
 .,.,.,.,.,.,.,.
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want a `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='state_num_x', columns='state_num_y',
               values='Sum_Prob', fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
state_num_y         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
state_num_x                                                                      
0            1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1            0.036936  0.740818  0.000000  0.000000  0.222245  0.000000  0.000000
2            0.036936  0.000000  0.000000  0.740818  0.000000  0.222245  0.000000
3            0.170284  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.829716  0.000000
4            1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
5            0.003599  0.088898  0.133347  0.000000  0.021336  0.012001  0.740818
6            0.015601  0.829716  0.000000  0.000000  0.154683  0.000000  0.000000
7            0.015601  0.000000  0.000000  0.829716  0.000000  0.154683  0.000000
```